# Using AWS Lambda to receive youtube push notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, youtube-api, aws-lambda, youtube-data-api

Is there a way using AWS lambda to receive notifications that a channel has uploaded a new video using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications (or any other method)?

I have currently tried using https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe using the URL for an API gateway which uses Lambda proxy to try and trigger my Lambda function but it doesn't seem to get there.

From here I want to be able to notify and store that information within AWS.

*Don't mind what language that needs to be used with Lambda*

Comment: Are you seeing anything in cloudwatch ?

Comment: No nothing appears, it's like it doesn't get to the function itself

Comment: It is a straight forward callback url. So Lambda should work.

Comment: @Kannaiyan thanks for your time, managed to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to work it out...

Created an open, unauthenticated API so that anything can talk to it with a basic AWS lambda 'Role' (not sure if that was important).

Then returned the `hub.challenge` in order to subscribe.

Comment: Any links to useful resources you found for working through this would be useful and strengthen your answer to this question.